# Accelerators not working in C++ in Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a program on `accelerators` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> | <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> | <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) on simple edit control,It performs some basic operations like `copy|paste|cut`...It consists of basic window and edit control when i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, WC_COMMAND prints nothing for these shortcuts. The minimal version of code of my program and resource script is

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define ID_SELECT 1010
#define ID_COPY 1011
#define ID_CUT 1012
#define ID_PASTE 1013
#define ID_ACCELERATORS 1014
using namespace std;
/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE hInstance;
/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */
hInstance=hThisInstance;
    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           _T("Code::Blocks Template Windows App"),       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
HACCEL hloadaccel=LoadAccelerators(hThisInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ACCELERATORS));
if(hloadaccel==NULL)
{
MessageBox(NULL,"problem with Accelerators","problem with Accelerators",MB_OK);
return 0;
}
    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
if(!TranslateAccelerator(hwnd,hloadaccel,&messages))
{
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
}
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {

case WM_CREATE:
{
HWND hwnd_Text=CreateWindowW(L"edit",L"", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_AUTOVSCROLL ,0,0,300,300,hwnd,(HMENU)1122,hInstance,NULL);
}                   /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
break;

case WM_COMMAND:
wcout<<LOWORD(wParam)<<endl;
wcout<<LOWORD(lParam)<<endl;
wcout<<HIWORD(wParam)<<endl;
wcout<<HIWORD(lParam)<<endl;
break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my resource code is

```
#include "Resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define ID_SELECT 1010
#define ID_COPY 1011
#define ID_CUT 1012
#define ID_PASTE 1013
#define ID_ACCELERATORS 1014
ID_ACCELERATORS ACCELERATORS
BEGIN
"a",ID_SELECT,VIRTKEY,CONTROL
"c",ID_COPY,VIRTKEY,CONTROL
"x",ID_CUT,CONTROL, VIRTKEY
"p",ID_PASTE,CONTROL,VIRTKEY
END
```

Comment: Your [ACCELERATORS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380610.aspx) definition is wrong.

Comment: so,could you give me some direction please !!!